# How can I use debug version of glibc to build a program?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, glibc

i want to debug something in glibc, so i want to use a debug version of glibc to build the program.
if i just use "gcc -o test test.c" to build the program,

> apt-get install libc6-dbg
>
> apt-get source libc6-dev

when i was debugging the programs,some val is told that it is optimized. and EIP is always jump back.

how can i debug the debug version of glibc.

Comment: Tried compiling with -g ?

Comment: @immibis: That doesn't do what the OP is asking.

Comment: actually this is not a seperate version but rather debug symbols for the main  library. since the main library is built with optimizations, yeah, it's quite expected that some functions are inlined and otherwise optimized out. you may want to compile libc from scratch with `-g` flag if you need unoptimized code, but even in this case there're some asm inlines.

Answer (score 4):

*Caveat*: I use fedora but it has a similar mechanism.

The debug package downloads an additional file that has the debug information you would get if you compiled with `-g` for `glibc`.

But, this package matches the *standard* build which is built *with* optimization (e.g. `-O2`).

It's the optimization that is causing the behavior you're seeing. So, the gdb "coverage" will be spotty.

What you want is a `glibc` version that is built with `-gdwarf-2` and `-O0`. AFAIK, you'll have to get that by building `glibc` yourself from the source.

You'll probably have to run the `configure` script and select the `-g` and `-O` options for the build. Then, run `make`. The exact details should be in the source documentation [or online] somewhere.

Then, you'll have to [forcibly] link your program against the built-from-source version.

Comment: GLIBC can not be built with `-O0`. It *requires* optimization to be on.

Comment: very useful for me,thank you very much! and -O1 is OK for me :)